# JQuery Mobile Validate Plugin "Required" not Working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Disclosure out of the way first, this is homework.

EDIT:
Okay, so I have the plugin working now, but only for stuff like numbers and email addresses, the default "always required" doesn't seem to be working, which is somewhat important. So to sum it up, if I set the class of a form element to "class="required"" it always validates regardless of if it is valid, whereas if I do something like "class="required number"" the validation works correctly.

OLD Text:
I need to use the JQuery Validate plugin on a JQM site with a form in it. The instruction via school is that all I need to do is change the class of a few of the form elements to "required" or something similar then just call .validate on the form.

Well, I've done this a few dozen times now and I can't get it to work, so maybe there is something in my code that is causing this issue, here are the relevant parts of my code:

As a note, I've only actually worked with JQM for a total of maybe one week before this, so I apologize fir any stupid mistakes/sloppiness.)

The form:

```
<!--Add char form-->
<div data-role="page" id="add-item" data-theme="a" >
    <!--I decided to edit my form from the previous week to be more flexable and generic for use in many different RPGs, and not just Dungeons and Dragons, as it was before.-->

    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Add New Character</h1>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="addCharForm">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="dateCreated">Date Created:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dateCreated">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="name">Age:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="charAge" value="">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charName">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="charName" placeholder="Character Name" class="required">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Choose character gender:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radioMale" value="Male">
            <label for="radioMale">Male</label>

            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radioFemale" value="Female">
            <label for="radioFemale">Female</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charAttrs">Describe your character's <b>attributes</b> in this field:</label>
            <textarea id="charAttrs"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charSkills">Describe your character's <b>skills</b> in this field:</label>
            <textarea id="charSkills"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charBio">Character Biography:</label>
            <textarea id="charBio"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charRating">Rate Your Character:</label>
            <input type="range" name="charRating" id="charRating" value="100" min="0" max="100">
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Character" data-theme="b">
        <input type="button" id="testBtn" value="Test">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$('#add-item').on('pageinit', function(){
console.log("In init");

    var myForm = $('#addCharForm');
        myForm.validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
                    var data = myForm.serializeArray();
        //TODO storeData(data);
    }
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just noticed the form has no ID, I fixed that, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So, something else I noticed just now, the .validate is firing, but it's ALWAYS coming back as validated regardless of if the data is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include `class="required"` on `<input>` and initialize your form as follows:

```
$("#nameOfTheForm").validate();
```